# OutLook Add-in command & not showing in Outlook

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin

I received a reply from microsoft
Validation Test Results:

" Your add-in must use add-in commands since it triggers on all messages or all appointments. Add-in commands have been introduced as they lead to a better, much more discoverable, native and engaging experience To find out how to implement add-in commands, please see this article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ENUS/library/office/mt267547.aspx

 Your add-in is not working in the Outlook 2016 Client on Windows 10 with Internet Explorer 11 or the Outlook 2013 Client on Windows 7 with Internet Explorer 11. We are unable to trigger your add-in when reading any email. Note: When the email is viewed in the Outlook Web App, we are able to insert your add-in."

I can not understand what I'm doing wrong. And Why my add-in not show in Outlook?

my manifest(all url work):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<OfficeApp
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
 xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
 xsi:type="MailApp">

  <Id>9230b645-1919-43a0-a568-1f2300fe06b0</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Information Technologies Ltd.</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Clobbi CRM" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Clobbi CRM"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="MY_URL" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="MY_URL" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://support.it.ua"></SupportUrl>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="MailBox" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings >
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>        
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="MY_URL"/>
        <RequestedHeight>450</RequestedHeight>        
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>    
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />

  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">

    <Description resid="residDescription" />

    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>

    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>        

         <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadDemoGroup">
                <Label resid="groupLabel" />
                 <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="paneReadButtonLabel" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="paneReadSuperTipTitle" />
                    <Description resid="paneReadSuperTipDescription" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="green-icon-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="green-icon-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="green-icon-80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="readTaskPaneUrl" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>

        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>

    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="green-icon-16" DefaultValue="MY_URL"/>
        <bt:Image id="green-icon-32" DefaultValue="MY_URL"/>
        <bt:Image id="green-icon-80" DefaultValue="MY_URL"/>     
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="functionFile" DefaultValue="MY_URL"/>
        <bt:Url id="readTaskPaneUrl" DefaultValue="MY URL"/>            
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="Clobbi CRM"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadButtonLabel" DefaultValue="Clobbi CRM"/>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipTitle" DefaultValue="Нажмите чтобы открыть Clobbi CRM."/>
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="paneReadSuperTipDescription" DefaultValue="Нажмите чтобы открыть Clobbi CRM."/>
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Description resid="residDescription" />` refers to a resid that isn't included in your `<Resources>`.

The reason it isn't showing up at all is related to this. When you define `VersionOverrides` Outlook for Windows will ignore the default settings (i.e. the settings you are "overriding"). When it encounters an error within `VersionOverrides` it cannot render the add-in command. Unfortunately Outlook will not "fall back" to the default handling, it will simply fail to load the add-in.